# Populating Spinner with Enum that has string resource

Tags: java, android, enums, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have an enum that has a property that maps to a string resource id, like so:

```
public enum MyEnum{

  FIRST(1,R.string.first_enum_desc),
  SECOND(2,R.string.second_enum_desc);

  private int mId;
  private int mDescriptionResourceId;

  private MyEnum(id,descriptionResourceId) {
      mId = id;
      mDescriptionResourceId = descriptionResourceId;
  }

  public toString(context){
      return context.getString(mDescriptionResourceId);
  }
}
```

I want to populate a spinner with the enum, the problem is simply using an adapter of my type:

```
Spinner spinner;
spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<MyEnum>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, MyEnum.values()));
```

I don't get the string resource description as the adapter implicitly calls toString(), which returns the enum name. I'm not sure how to proceed here. No matter what I need the Context to get the string values. Could someone suggest the best way to achieve what I am looking for? I just need a point in the right direction. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should build your own ArrayAdapter. And then override the methods getView() and getDropDownView.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyEnum> {

    public MyAdapter (Context context) {
        super(context, 0, MyEnum.values());
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         CheckedTextView text= (CheckedTextView) convertView;

         if (text== null) {
             text = (CheckedTextView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,  parent, false);
         }

         text.setText(getItem(position).getDescriptionResourceId());

         return text;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        CheckedTextView text = (CheckedTextView) convertView;

        if (text == null) {
            text = (CheckedTextView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,  parent, false);
        }

        text.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());

        return text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to retrieve your enum provided its view position, or its item position is getting its position : as you pass the values of the enum, they'll be displayed in the order they're declared. For example in an `OnItemClickListener` :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    MyEnum value = MyEnum.values()[position];
    ...
}
```

---

Another solution would be to retrieve the text of the view then parse the enum using Enum.valueOf, but this requires to know the id of the `TextView` that displays the item and seems to complicated compared to the first solution. Something like :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String text = ((TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.mytextview)).getText();
    MyEnum value = MyEnum.valueOf(text);
}
```

And last, you can also retrieve the enum from the adapter and cast it, for example like this :

```
MyEnum.class.cast(myListView.getAdapter().getItem(position))
```

Comment: Another solution would be to retrieve the text of the view then parse the enum using `Enum.valueOf`, but this requires to know the id of the `TextView that displays the item and seems to complicated compared to the first solution.

Comment: And last, you can also retrieve the enum from the adapter and cast it, for example like this : `MyEnum.class.cast(myListView.getAdapter().getItem(position))`.

Comment: @Antonie Marques - thanks for the response. Sorry but I'm not seeing how what you have here will help me display the string resource value in the Spinner itself. Could you explain?

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood the question, i thought you wanted to get back an enum from the adapter. But using an `ArrayAdapter` as you already made it is straight forward, because `ListView` populates the views with the `toString` value of each item. Isn't that what's you already made ?

Comment: Ok i understood. The other answer provided by @bbrakenhoff is correct : you should override the methods related to `getView` of `Adapter`